# Uploading a single Sharepoint document with metadata

Tags: c#, sharepoint, csom

I defined terms in the Term Store Management Tool which I added as "Managed Metadata" columns in a document library.
I want to upload a document and to update its "Managed Metadata" columns.
In order to do so, I wrote the following code:

```
    void UploadDocument(Document document)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ClientContext context = SPHelper.GetClientContext())
            {
                List library = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("MyDocumentLibrary");
                FileCreationInformation fileInfo = new FileCreationInformation
                {
                    Url = "MyFileTarget",
                    Content = document.Content,
                    Overwrite = true
                };
                File file = library.RootFolder.Files.Add(fileInfo);
                ListItem item = file.ListItemAllFields;

                item["RegularColumn"] = "some data";
                item["Metadata"] = "some other data";
                item.Update();
                context.ExecuteQuery(); // "The given guid does not exist in the term store." Exception thrown
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogHelper.RecordError("Failed to upload document", ex, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        }
    }
```

I can upload a file and update its regular columns but I can't update the Metadata columns.

Is there a way to specify item["Metadata"] GUID ?

Comment: It is a TaxonomyField, so you have to set a "TaxonomyFieldValue". https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-csom/jj166936(v=office.15)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Term Guid can be found in Term Store:

[image]

Add reference to Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll:

[image]

Here is the code snippet to set managed metadata field value with TaxonomyFieldValue class:

```
            using (ClientContext context = new ClientContext(sharePointSite))
            {
                FileCreationInformation FCInfo = new FileCreationInformation();
                FCInfo.Url = "http://sp2016/sites/dev/Shared%20Documents/Test.txt";
                FCInfo.Overwrite = true;
                FCInfo.Content = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fileToUpload);

                Web web = context.Web;
                List library = web.Lists.GetByTitle(libraryName);
                Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File uploadfile = library.RootFolder.Files.Add(FCInfo);

                ListItem item = uploadfile.ListItemAllFields;
                item["Title"] = "some data";
                var fields = library.Fields;
                var field = fields.GetByInternalNameOrTitle("managedcolumn");
                context.Load(fields);
                context.Load(field);
                context.ExecuteQuery();
                var taxKeywordField = context.CastTo<TaxonomyField>(field);
                TaxonomyFieldValue termValue = new TaxonomyFieldValue();
                termValue.Label = "TermC";
                termValue.TermGuid = "045830f1-f51e-4bac-b631-5815a7b6125f";
                termValue.WssId = 3;
                taxKeywordField.SetFieldValueByValue(item, termValue);
                item.Update();
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                uploadfile.CheckIn("testcomment", CheckinType.MajorCheckIn);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

            }
```

[image]

Comment: I tried this before posting. My issue is that it doesn't compile.

Error 1: 'TaxonomyField' does not contain a definition for 'SetFieldValueByValue' and no accessible extension method 'SetFieldValueByValue' accepting a first argument of type 'TaxonomyField' could be found.

Error 2: The type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'ClientRuntimeContext.CastTo<T>(ClientObject)'. There is no implicit reference conversion from 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy.TaxonomyField' to 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject'.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft.SharePoint.Taxonomy 15.0.0

Comment: I also tested in SharePoint 2013, still works, make sure you reference the correct dll in your solution.
It's Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Taxonomy.dll not Microsoft.Taxonomy.dll

Comment: I will add a capture about reference dll, please check it.

Comment: It turns out it didn't work because the SharePoint dependency I was using was too old indeed. I switched to Microsoft.SharePoint2019.CSOM and it is now working fine. Thank you.